# Can you apply an Authorizer to the entire API in AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger, aws-api-gateway

I am using AWS Api Gateway and have written a custom authorizer. The authorizer works for whicher api methods I have it applied to, but I would like every method in the API to use it.

Is there a way, either through the console or using a swagger doc, to apply the authorizer to all of the api methods without needing to go through each one manually?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this?

Comment: @dkr88 No I didnt. I dont think there is a way. The best thing I could do was just generate the API off of a swagger doc. It was easier to duplicate the authorizer reference by copying and pasting as opposed to going through the management console.